# How to password protect a directory in linux? without zipping, changing file permission or encrypting?

Tags: linux, command-line, file-permissions, password-protection

I'm a user on a public linux server. We have a public shared folder which all users can use.
I want to create a folder that I only want a few users to access. This can be done in the following ways:

1. Create a group of users you want to provide access and then change the folder permission to that group
   I can't do this because I don't have root privileges. Even if I ask the admin to create a group for me, I'll have to occasionally add/remove users from the group. This is not feasible
2. Encrypt and zip the folder using "zip re" command. This will zip the folder and everytime a user needs to access the contents, he needs to unzip. This becomes infeasible when my folder grow up to be large.
3. creating and mounting an encrypted directory with encfs. Here you have to maintain two folders - an encrypted folder and a mount point folder. And everytime you need to access a file/folder you need to mount it to the mount point. This again requires a lot of copying a moving and is inefficient

What I'm looking for is a simple process. Enter password and you can view the contents of the folder. Wrong password- access denied. Is there anything in linux that does this?

Comment: I voted to close your question because I think the [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) sites of the StackExchange network are better for this question; this site here (StackOverflow) is only intended for questions related to **writing** computer programs.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way of limiting access to a directory (aka "folder") in Unix filesystems is to use groups in the owner/group/other Unix permissions mechanism. This does require admin permissions to create and modify the group and its members. So, how can you do this without such admin authority?

The same way that arbitrarily complex access and change permissions have been accomplished since very early Unix implementations. It's not simple point'n'click, nor even simple command line; but "arbitrarily complex permissons" are inherently complex. What was done was use the owner/group/other permissions to limit access to a single userid, then provide setuid programs to get allowed access to the files. The arbitrarily complex permission logic was in the setuid programs. This does not require any admin type permissions.

So if you wanted to provide read access for a list of userids Mondays and Wednesdays between 10 and 2 GMT, and a different list of userids Tuesdays and Thursdays between 9 and 1 GMT, you could encode that logic in your program and direct users to run that program -- if they met the criteria, the output would be the desired file.

Yup, this is probably overkill for what you want.

You might try creating a password protected or encrypted archive file; authorized users would have the password and could extract the contents. Changes would be sent to you and you could overwrite or update the archive. This means a delay in propagating changes, and requirements for local copies of the archive for each user, causing even more delay. So it's not a very good solution either. This is your solution #2.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the only options currently available to unix users. Of all three options, creating a group and providing read/write access to the group is the best way.